# Hibernate.cfg.xml not found - Project with Modules

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle, project-structure

I have a project setup below. I've created services to run alongside android apps locally using java spark and hibernate.

When I try to run up the services module I get /hibernate.cfg.xml not found. This is located in the resources folder of services module.

If I copy this module folder outside of the project and import into it's own project it runs perfectly.

Why doesn't it work as a module? Gradle is used to manage dependencies.

company
  - services (java)
  - common (java)
  - model (java)
  - app1 (android)
  - app2 (android)

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question. I think this could either be an intelliJ or gradle problem below are points leading to the solution. I compared the setup and outputs of the solo project and module project.

- The run configurations were setup correctly for both.
- Interestingly the build folders for each were identical.
- Printing out the files and folders on the classpath at run time revealed that the hibernate.cfg.xml file wasn't on the module project but was on the solo project.

Using this piece of gradle I was able to get the resources onto the classpath:

```
sourceSets {
    main { 
        output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/main" 
    }
}
```